# Gulp not creating any files

Tags: build, automation, gulp, build-tools

I created a project for becoming familiar with build tools. My folder structure for this project looks like so:

```
+ my-project
|-- + sources
|------ index.html
|-- + www
|-- gulpfile.js
```

And the contents of `glupfile.js` are:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('sources/index.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/index.html'));
});
```

For simplicity's sake I `chmod`'d everything in this folder (and all parent folders) to `777` - so there's no issue of file permissions.

Yet when I run `gulp`, I get the following output:

```
user@server:~/my-project# gulp
[00:05:09] Using gulpfile ~/my-project/gulpfile.js
[00:05:09] Starting 'default'...
[00:05:09] Finished 'default' after 11 ms
```

and absolutely no files are created. The `www` folder remains barren.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave out the index.html. You should always pipe your files into a folder(desc) and not to another file(index.html)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
gulp.src('sources/index.html')
.pipe(gulp.dest('www'));
});
```